# Stop process of webcam in java netbeans

Tags: java

I want to capture an image using an available webcam. I have successfully accessed the webcam but I couldn't stop the webcam process. I want to stop the webcam process using a stop button. How can I accomplish this? This my code:

```
public Component componen() throws IOException , NoPlayerException, CannotRealizeException
        {

            Component comp_video;
            MediaLocator loo = new MediaLocator("vfw://0");
            try {
                broadcast = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(loo);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(CapturImage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (NoPlayerException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(CapturImage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (CannotRealizeException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(CapturImage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            broadcast.start();

            if((comp_video = broadcast.getVisualComponent()) != null)
            {
                comp_video.setSize(321,228);
                return comp_video;

            }
            else
            {
                     return null;
            }

    }

public void capture_image()
{
    FrameGrabbingControl grab = (FrameGrabbingControl)    broadcast.getControl("javax.media.control.FrameGrabbingControl");
     javax.media.Buffer buff = grab.grabFrame();

     BufferToImage buffer =new BufferToImage((VideoFormat) buff.getFormat());
     img = buffer.createImage(buff);

    }

public void set_iamge_label(final JLabel lb)
{
    Thread web = new Thread(){

    public void run(){


    capture_image();
    Rectangle rect = lb.getBounds();
    Image img1 = img.getScaledInstance(rect.width,rect.height,Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
    lb.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(img1));  
    }
    };

    web.start();
}
```

Comment: It's means Web camera

Comment: Hi, maybe it would help if you made your question a little bit more specific. For example, "After getting an image with Java Media's FrameGrabbingControl, how do I stop the camera?"

Comment: It looks like your `broadcast` object should implement the [Controller interface](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/apidocs/index.html) and you can call the [close](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/apidocs/index.html) method on that.